# Celery Task on different servers starting simultaneously

Tags: django, celery

I have two instances of Django Celery code running on two different servers for redundancy accessing a common database on another server. I notice that celery beat starting the same task simultaneously on two server when the job get submitted by the users. This creates a race condition and updates the database twice. How to prevent this by holding the task in one server while another similar task has started in another server?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a lock to prevent two tasks from executing concurrently, there's a page in the celery docs http://ask.github.io/celery/cookbook/tasks.html with an example of how to do this.  Careful your implementation doesn't get stuck in a sort of dead lock, and that you set a timeout on your locks so that if a worker crashes, it doesn't hold onto the lock indefinitely.

```
# Example from the link above
from celery.task import Task
from django.core.cache import cache
from django.utils.hashcompat import md5_constructor as md5
from djangofeeds.models import Feed

LOCK_EXPIRE = 60 * 5 # Lock expires in 5 minutes

class FeedImporter(Task):
    name = "feed.import"

    def run(self, feed_url, **kwargs):
        logger = self.get_logger(**kwargs)

        # The cache key consists of the task name and the MD5 digest
        # of the feed URL.
        feed_url_digest = md5(feed_url).hexdigest()
        lock_id = "%s-lock-%s" % (self.name, feed_url_hexdigest)

        # cache.add fails if if the key already exists
        acquire_lock = lambda: cache.add(lock_id, "true", LOCK_EXPIRE)
        # memcache delete is very slow, but we have to use it to take
        # advantage of using add() for atomic locking
        release_lock = lambda: cache.delete(lock_id)

        logger.debug("Importing feed: %s" % feed_url)
        if acquire_lock():
            try:
                feed = Feed.objects.import_feed(feed_url)
            finally:
                release_lock()
            return feed.url

        logger.debug(
            "Feed %s is already being imported by another worker" % (
                feed_url))
        return
```

This pattern requires a cache server that is used to acquire the lock.  When the task starts, it will acquire a lock in the cache server based on a key, such as "my_task", then when your task completes it will release that lock.  Any other tasks that are started should perhaps have a `while` loop that waits until it can acquire a lock.  Redis locks are atomic, which means the operations which acquire the lock do not happen concurrently, and only one task will be able to acquire the lock.